# Nuxt3 request error Invalid Url () Server.nodeHandler

Tags: npm, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, npm-start

I updated my node and npm version to v16.18.0 and 18.19.2 respectively. After updating I removed all my node_modules and nuxt directory and re-installed my packages.

My `package.json` looks as follows:

```json
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/tailwindcss": "^5.1.2",
    "@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio": "^0.4.0",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
    "@vueuse/nuxt": "^8.7.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.3",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/vue": "^1.6.4",
    "@heroicons/vue": "^1.0.6",
    "@pinia/nuxt": "^0.1.9",
    "@tailwindcss/line-clamp": "^0.4.0",
    "@vueuse/core": "^8.7.4",
    "chart.js": "^3.8.0",
    "chartjs-adapter-date-fns": "^2.0.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.28.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.5",
    "json-to-csv-export": "^1.1.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "pinia": "^2.0.14",
    "pinia-plugin-persistedstate": "^1.6.1",
    "vue-chartjs": "^4.1.1",
    "vue-gtag": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-tailwind-datepicker": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

With my `nuxt.config.ts` I added some packages to modules and build transpile:

```js
import {defineNuxtConfig} from 'nuxt'

// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  components: true,
  modules: ['@nuxtjs/tailwindcss', '@pinia/nuxt', '@vueuse/nuxt'],
  build: {
    transpile: ['@heroicons/vue', 'date-fns', 'chartjs-adapter-date-fns', 'chart.js']
  },
  tailwindcss: {
    jit: true,
    exposeConfig: true,
    configPath: '~/tailwind.config.js'
  }
})
```

However, installing and running nuxt3 I get the following error:

```
npm run dev
[nuxt] [request error] Invalid URL ()
  at async $fetchRaw2 (<dir>/node_modules/ohmyfetch/dist/chunks/fetch.mjs:131:20)
  at async default (<dir>/node_modules/@nuxt/vite-builder/dist/runtime/vite-node.mjs:16:23)
  at async Object.renderToString (<dir>/node_modules/vue-bundle-renderer/dist/index.mjs:264:19)
  at async <dir>/.nuxt/dev/index.mjs:465:20
  at async <dir>/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:420:19
  at async Server.nodeHandler (<dir>/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:370:7)
```

It is unclear to me how to proceed from here, since this error is very vague.

Comment: NPM is at v18 now? You're sure about that? Also, the error occurred only after the upgrade + package addition, nothing more? Which packages did you added to module and transpile exactly?

Comment: Yes the npm version is correct. I didn't add anything else. I didn't change nuxt config. After deleting the package-lock.json:

npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @pinia/nuxt@"^0.1.9" from the root project
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: vue@2.6.14
npm ERR! node_modules/vue
npm ERR!   peer vue@">= 2.5 < 2.7" from @vue/composition-api@1.7.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@vue/composition-api
npm ERR!     peerOptional @vue/composition-api@"^1.4.0" from pinia@2.0.23
npm ERR!     node_modules/pinia
npm ERR!       pinia@"^2.0.23" from the root project